# HTTPD Proxy Change Response Address

Tags: apache, redirect, proxy, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf

My setup is as follows:

```
client -> proxy(dnsname eg. https://test.com) -> Jetty webapp(1.2.3.4)
```

The webapp sends a redirect response back (to an authentication webapp) to the client. It automatically points to the proxy via dnsname eg. https://proxy/auth and cannot be configured further.

The issue with this is the webapp will pass redirects back to the client and the client cannot resolve https://proxy as I can't make it a dns entry. Is it then possible for the proxy to intercept the traffic from the webapp (https://proxy) and change it to https://test.com? Even better can the proxy autodetect the entry dns name and append it to any responses from the webapp?

I'd envisioned the following:

client request https://test.com/page1-> hits proxy which resolves to webapp -> webapp gives redirect response via https://proxy/auth -> proxy intercepts and changes redirect to https://test.com/auth

I need this so that everything behind the proxy isn't machine nor ip specific. I can shift and deploy to any environment.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out eventually. You can just modify the redirect headers in the location field.

```
Header edit Location "(^http[s]?://proxy)" "https://whatevernameyouwant"
```